# Why a mismatch between errno 34 and code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, posix

So if I run this simple call in node.js v0.6.7 on OS X 10.6.8 with a bogus path, I get an error, as expected.

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.stat("/tmp/foo", function(error, stat) {
    return console.log(error);
});
```

It prints this output:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/foo'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/tmp/foo' }
```

My question is, according to `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` on my system, `ENOENT` should have code 2, so why is this error saying errno `34` (ERANGE in errno.h), but pairing it with the error message from `ENOENT`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

node.js translates system `errno`s to internal "errnos" (see `deps/uv/include/uv.h` and `uv_translate_sys_error` in `deps/uv/src/unix/error.c` or `deps/uv/src/win/error.c` for a mapping) as to achieve a common representation for error-conditions under Windows and Unix.

34 is the node.js-errno for `ENOENT`, so everything is alright.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks. But why does `require('constants').ENOENT` report 2 in that case? Is there another way to get Node's errnos?

Comment: A bit late, but maybe helpful for others: It seems the errnos are not exposed by node. You can use the npm module [errno-codes](https://npmjs.org/package/errno-codes) to get predefined constants for the errnos.

Comment: I swear this is a nodejs bug. It should be `-2` per the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_errno

Answer (score 4):

It seems that node.js changed the `errno` with 0.12.0. `ENOENT` is `-2`now.

So it is probably better to check for `code === 'ENOENT'`

Answer (score -2):

because you haven't created the folder /tmp/foo yet and it's looking for that folder
(when i added a few error handling lines to my code, the console spat out the same error code and it was because i had not yet created the directory i was telling it to save my images to)

Comment: read carefully the question (he already knows that the directory doesn't exists)